# Group By Pandas With condition

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe

```
id           type             ip
1            mcma             123
1            mcms             124
1            mcda             125
1            mcds             126
2            cic              127
2            cmc              128
```

I want to become dataframe using pandas by group by function with id and apply type to list, ip is ip of mcma if id has type mcma, other is '-'

```
id           child                                                      ip
1            [{type: mcma, ip:123}, ..., {type:mcds, ip:126}]           123
2            [{type:cic, ip:127}, {type:cmc, ip:128}]                   -
```

Currently, I just get id and type correct, I dont know how to get ip columns. Current code:

```
df = (df.groupby(["id"], as_index=True).apply(lambda x: x[["type", "ip"]].to_dict('record')).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'child'}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is replace `ip` if not match `mcma` to `NaN` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then aggregate `list` and first value of `ip`:

```
df = (df.assign(ip = df['ip'].where(df['type'].eq('mcma')),
                type = df[['type','ip']].apply(lambda x: dict(x), axis=1))
        .groupby('id')
        .agg(child=('type',list), ip=('ip','first'))
        .reset_index())

df['ip'] = df['ip'].fillna('-')
print (df)
   id                                              child     ip
0   1  [{'type': 'mcma', 'ip': 123}, {'type': 'mcms',...    123
1   2  [{'type': 'cic', 'ip': 127}, {'type': 'cmc', '...      -
```

Comment: if I want to child is list of dictionary like [{type: mcma, ip: 123}, {type:mcms, ip:124}, {type: mcda, ip:125}, {type:mcds, ip:126}]. How can I get this?